# Java git client using jgit

Tags: java, jsch, passphrase, jgit

I am having some difficulties with a git client written in java. I am using the jGit library to connect through ssh on the git server. The problem is that i don't know how to specify the path to the private key and the passphrase for it. I couldn't find any examples in the jGit documentation about what functions i need to call. From what i read the jGit library is using JSch to connect to the server using ssh and JSch supports private keys and passphrases. Does anyone have any experience with this or has some working code?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't ever use jGit, but from looking at the Javadocs (which are seemingly not online browsable, [but can be downloaded](http://eclipse.org/jgit/download/)) you need to configure a SshSessionFactory (i.e. create a subclass of JSchConfigSessionFactory, and override its `configure` method).

The [JSch](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/index.html?com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html) object supports private keys with its `addIdentity` methods, and the passphrases can be given with [UserInfo](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/index.html?com/jcraft/jsch/UserInfo.html) objects to each individual JSch [Session](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/index.html?com/jcraft/jsch/Session.html).

*(Disclaimer: The JSch Javadoc was written by me.)*

Comment: @azertys it would be helpful if you could share some more information, how it worked for you. I am still struggling to get this thru. I get errors :com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
 at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
 at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:117)

Comment: I understand it has been close to 6 years but any help on this would be awesome.

Comment: Sorry, i don't have the code of my app anymore but if you can post here some of the non working code maybe me or somebody else here can help you out.