# "Auth fail" error with maven-scm-provider-jgit during release:prepare

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, jgit, maven-scm

I am on a windows machine where git command line is not installed. I have installed GitExtensions and an EGit and this is sufficient for me (until now).

Now I wanted to perform a maven release to BinTray, following this guide:
[Publishing releases using Github, Bintray and maven-release-plugin](http://veithen.github.io/2013/05/26/github-bintray-maven-release-plugin.html)

Running:

```
mvn -Prelease release:prepare
```

Produces this output:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building xxxxx 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.4.1:prepare (default-cli) @ xxxxx ---
[INFO] Resuming release from phase 'scm-commit-release'
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git add -- pom.xml"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Users\jbr\git\yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.770 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-12T20:17:24+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/989M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.1:prepare (default-cli) on project xxxxx: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-add command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[ERROR] operable program or batch file.
```

Absolutely fair, I never use the git command from the windows shell and I never set up the pageant.exe stuff. (for details see [this answer to the question “Why git can't remember my passphrase under Windows”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4356869/91497)).

My second idea was to use the [maven-scm-provider-jgit](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-providers/maven-scm-providers-git/maven-scm-provider-jgit/) to not depend on the `git` command line.

The output is now:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building xxxxx 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.4.1:prepare (default-cli) @ xxxxx ---
[INFO] Change the default 'git' provider implementation to 'jgit'.
[INFO] Resuming release from phase 'scm-commit-release'
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[INFO] push changes to remote... refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
[INFO] fetch url: git@github.com:jmini/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.git
[INFO] push url: git@github.com:jmini/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.git
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.1:prepare (default-cli) on project xxxxx: An error is occurred in the checkin process: Exception while executing SCM command. JGit checkin failure! git@github.com:jmini/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.git: Auth fail -> [Help 1]
```

Much better, but still no luck.

My guess is that the private key and the passphrase are not loaded. How should I configure them?

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4791460) suggests that for some SCM providers, it is possible to specify the credentials in the `<servers>` section of `settings.xml`. The domain name of the repository should be used as `<id>`.
According to the last comment with `scm:git:ssh://git@bitbucket.org/{account}/{project}` used in the `<developerConnection>`, this entry is working in the `settings.xml`:

```
<server>
  <id>bitbucket.org</id>
  <privateKey>/c/Users/neil.hunt/.ssh/id_rsa</privateKey>
</server>
```

Is this construct supported by the JGit SCM provider?

---

When searching for “Auth failed” error, I found this related question (plain JGit, no maven plugin):

[How do you set the configuration for jschconfigsessionfactory for jgit so that pull and push work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502452/how-do-you-set-the-configuration-for-jschconfigsessionfactory-for-jgit-so-that-p)

Comment: Why do you use an acient version of [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/). I can't see if you use an up-to-date version of maven-scm-provider?

Comment: No reason (copy paste from some website). I have updated `maven-release-plugin` to `2.5.2` and I use `maven-scm-provider-jgit`version `1.9.4`.

Comment: Have you tried to run your release on plain windows command line instead within cygwin?