# JGIT TransportConfigCallback implementation with Apache MINA

Tags: configuration, openssh, jgit, apache-mina

JGit used to rely on JSch as its transport provider, but changed because JSch does not accept certain keys, including some OpenSSH ones.

If you are using a passphrase-encrypted key with JGit, the recommended approach with JSch used to be [to override a configuration callback, as shown in this blog article](https://blog.sebastian-daschner.com/entries/access-git-from-java).

The alternative is to [set a shared session factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502452/how-do-you-set-the-configuration-for-jschconfigsessionfactory-for-jgit-so-that-p#answer-15290861) and this [also what the Apache MINA team recommends with a pointer to the cost of creating sessions on demand](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/master/docs/git.md#user-content-client-side).

However, my issue with this is that it sets a specific provider for the whole system scope. Consequently, I would like to implement [`TransportConfigCallback`](https://archive.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/TransportConfigCallback.html). Ultimately, this requires to adapt [`SshSessionFactory`](https://archive.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/SshSessionFactory.html) to MINA's session initialization code and produce a [`RemoteSession`](https://archive.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/RemoteSession.html).

Has anyone done this or seen any boilerplate code?

Answer (score 0):

Self answer after some research: The interface to MINA in JGit is deliberately set closed. The driver only accepts a regular Git configuration directory. And this is the key to configuring the system:

- Provide a different git configuration directory for each user.
- Provide regular git configuration (git config) files underneath for all special settings
- JGit has classes to write Git configurations, so you do not need to write any parsing and serialisation code.

I will update this answer with pertinent links to the classes and source code locations involved.

From [version 5.5 the factory can be configured for this usecase](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547619). See [NoFilesSshTest.java](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jgit/jgit.git/tree/org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/sshd/NoFilesSshTest.java) for details on how to use a database to provide connection information.